# Webview disable opening installed Apps by clicking on link

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, uiwebview

I have a simple `WebView` in my Project. The user can google and search for anything. The problem that I have right now is that by clicking on certain links, I get automatically redirected to the specific app (if I have it installed).

Example:

I have the Adidas App on my iPhone and tap on a "Adidas"-Link -> I get redirected to the Adidas app. That should **not** happen. Instead the link should be opened within my `WebView`.

This is my `webView`:

```
  bool _isLoading = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Web View Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl:
                    'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/de/product/48276/adidas-4d-futurecraft?country_override=DE&utm_content=cpcadssnscf&gclid=CjwKCAjwoduRBhA4EiwACL5RP4YhIZ818uzJTmO8gKLX3Z6Vvff740OjFsxs2nL0yzf-uGyzW9ak6RoCxyEQAvD_BwE',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                },
                javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                  _extractDataJSChannel(context),
                },
                onPageStarted: (String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = true;
                  });
                },
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    _imagesWithSize = [];

                    _currentUrl = url;
                    _isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.goBack();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.goForward();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RoundedCornersTextButton(
              title: 'Google',
              isEnabled: !_isLoading,
              onTap: () async {
                await _controller.loadUrl('https://www.google.com');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Is there any way to prevent other apps from opening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is some issue with the webview.

Actually there are a few websites that when you open them, they check if you are using a mobile phone and If that is the case, they also check If you already have the app installed on your device. If that is also true, the mobile app is opened by default.

Can you please go to some other website using the google search (inside webview) and see if the same behaviour exists ?

Comment: yes thats exactly the case. But I want to prevent that. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: @Chris did you find any solution?

Comment: no, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @Chris Can you tell me what is the link to this webview?

Comment: it's the official `webview_flutter` : https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Aliexpress. When you try to open a link in the browser, it detects the app and asks you to 'Open in another app.' I noticed that the initial URL was changed and starts with 'aliexpress://product/detail?...'.

So, to prevent this, in the 'onNavigationRequest' method, there is a validation of the URL on HTTP or HTTPS. In case the URL is changed to open the app, it will be ignored.

```
 WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onWebResourceError: _handleError,  
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (!(request.url.startsWith('https://') || request.url.startsWith('http://'))) {
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    ),
  )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(_url));
```